# Google map center based on supplying the geometry data

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am passing the url to google map.data.loadGeoJson(url) api. This properly access the geometry data and display the markers on the map. What i am unable to do is to put the map center to the location where these map markers are created.
My code is like this

```
 var map;    
 function initialize(url) {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     zoom: 17,
     center: {lat: 26.925, lng: 49.726}
   });

   // [START snippet-load]
   // Load GeoJSON
   map.data.loadGeoJson(url);
   // [END snippet-load]


   // [START snippet-style]
   // Set the stroke width, and fill color for each polygon
   var featureStyle = {
     fillColor: 'red',
     strokeWeight: 1
   }
   map.data.setStyle(featureStyle);
   map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        //alert('feature'+feature)
        var locCounter = 0;
        while(locCounter == 0) {
            //var mylat = LatLngObject.lat();
            var key = feature["j"]["j"][0]["j"][0]["j"][0];
            if(typeof key == 'undefined') {
                break;
            }
            var counter =[];
            var count = 0;              
            for(var key1 in key) {
                counter[count] = key[key1];                                     
                if(count >= 1) {                        
                    locCounter = 1;
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
         if(locCounter == 1) {
             map.setCenter({lat: counter[0], lng: counter[1]});              
        }           
    //  if(locCounter == 0) {               
        //var lang = feature["j"]["j"][0]["j"][0]["j"][0]["A"];
        //var lat = feature["j"]["j"][0]["j"][0]["j"][0]["F"];
        //map.setCenter({lat: lang, lng: lat});
        //locCounter = 1;
    //   }          

        var color = 'red';

        return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
          fillColor: color,
          strokeColor: color,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });
      });
 }
```

In above code you can see that i am trying to read the feature object to get the longitude and latitude but problem is every time the index is not same at all. so some time it dosent set the correct center. I want to know that how can i set the center from automatically from the data which i am trying to display on the map.

my url return geo json data like this

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:4326"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                39.1206730032052,
                                21.9142977383938
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1187366628205,
                                21.9142686642138
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1187346942698,
                                21.9147698234573
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1187175621506,
                                21.9149506624937
                            ],
                            [
                                39.118656647949,
                                21.9151905121632
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1185728909215,
                                21.9154056154381
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1185005553069,
                                21.9155712259242
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1179679129608,
                                21.9166968299528
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1176224152226,
                                21.9166930228153
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1174549011679,
                                21.9166701799897
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1173568673744,
                                21.9166473371639
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1172921460352,
                                21.9166283014759
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1137560290344,
                                21.9153067488333
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1138593627724,
                                21.9148531312384
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1064385945506,
                                21.9123032285723
                            ],
                            [
                                39.107569441325,
                                21.9086256288201
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1073748688327,
                                21.9086072633469
                            ],
                            [
                                39.107205332236,
                                21.9085656227793
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1070120010293,
                                21.9084704443391
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1068751820215,
                                21.9083603942674
                            ],
                            [
                                39.106753234645,
                                21.9082027549759
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1059115003141,
                                21.9067334378047
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1058490394627,
                                21.9065906701445
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1057955015902,
                                21.9064508768104
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1057776556326,
                                21.9063110834761
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1057776556326,
                                21.9061504698582
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1059352949243,
                                21.9054098626202
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1059858584705,
                                21.9052700692861
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1060929342158,
                                21.9050975583632
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1062416505286,
                                21.9049369447453
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1063544369804,
                                21.9048531877179
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1070597092225,
                                21.9044120356475
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1072253197085,
                                21.9043135259617
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1075679620934,
                                21.9041403012006
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1074993939589,
                                21.9039598190834
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1074565636607,
                                21.9037980157348
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1073899387526,
                                21.9036552480746
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1072471710921,
                                21.9033126056897
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1127949240849,
                                21.9025555008554
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1132113297609,
                                21.9030849309291
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1134909164293,
                                21.9034477987326
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1138418869276,
                                21.90392666526
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1139430140203,
                                21.9040902532041
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1156304484503,
                                21.9067487060129
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1137855730171,
                                21.9078258086948
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1137290608183,
                                21.9078525776312
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1135595242216,
                                21.9079537047239
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1134881403914,
                                21.9080131912491
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1133602443623,
                                21.9081321642993
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1132298816253,
                                21.9082940033398
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1131747376165,
                                21.9083760233606
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1130605234882,
                                21.9086008824257
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1130141239987,
                                21.9087900495757
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1129927088495,
                                21.9090120532875
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1129965159872,
                                21.9090977138836
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1130174552439,
                                21.9092880707641
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1130498159137,
                                21.9095755096537
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1130783694458,
                                21.9098362985798
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1131773550236,
                                21.9105501368817
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1132059085558,
                                21.9106890974044
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1132573049135,
                                21.9108318650647
                            ],
                            [
                                39.113329640528,
                                21.9109765362938
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1134210118307,
                                21.9111040754037
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1135295152526,
                                21.9112335180826
                            ],
                            [
                                39.113601850867,
                                21.9112982394217
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1137255828395,
                                21.9114010321372
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1138340862614,
                                21.9114714641831
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1139197468575,
                                21.9115152462655
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1141253322883,
                                21.9115970997241
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1150433174384,
                                21.911944570432
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1186921019178,
                                21.9131436998059
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1206730032052,
                                21.9137861542774
                            ],
                            [
                                39.1206730032052,
                                21.9142977383938
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "PHID": 167781,
                "LMID": 167690,
                "FILE_ID": 167782,
                "CREATED_DATE": "2015-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "CREATED_BY": "Admin01",
                "FILE_FEATURE_ID": 1
            },
            "id": "LAYERS_GEOMETRY_DATA.167783"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does your GeoJSON data look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip i have updated the string which i am getting from the url .

Answer (score 0):

Process through the GeoJSON adding each coordinate to a bounds object, then do a map.fitBounds with that bounds. Note the code below only supports MultiPolygons, but can be extended if you have other types.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2ks04z3k/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  // Create a simple map.
  features = [];
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137.883
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
  // process the loaded GeoJSON data.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.data, 'addfeature', function(e) {
    if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiPolygon') {
      var multi = e.feature.getGeometry().getArray();
      for (var k = 0; k < multi.length; k++) {
        var polys = multi[k].getArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < polys.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < polys[i].getLength(); j++) {
            bounds.extend(polys[i].getAt(j));
          }
        }
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [
              39.1206730032052,
              21.9142977383938
            ],
            [
              39.1187366628205,
              21.9142686642138
            ],
            [
              39.1187346942698,
              21.9147698234573
            ],
            [
              39.1187175621506,
              21.9149506624937
            ],
            [
              39.118656647949,
              21.9151905121632
            ],
            [
              39.1185728909215,
              21.9154056154381
            ],
            [
              39.1185005553069,
              21.9155712259242
            ],
            [
              39.1179679129608,
              21.9166968299528
            ],
            [
              39.1176224152226,
              21.9166930228153
            ],
            [
              39.1174549011679,
              21.9166701799897
            ],
            [
              39.1173568673744,
              21.9166473371639
            ],
            [
              39.1172921460352,
              21.9166283014759
            ],
            [
              39.1137560290344,
              21.9153067488333
            ],
            [
              39.1138593627724,
              21.9148531312384
            ],
            [
              39.1064385945506,
              21.9123032285723
            ],
            [
              39.107569441325,
              21.9086256288201
            ],
            [
              39.1073748688327,
              21.9086072633469
            ],
            [
              39.107205332236,
              21.9085656227793
            ],
            [
              39.1070120010293,
              21.9084704443391
            ],
            [
              39.1068751820215,
              21.9083603942674
            ],
            [
              39.106753234645,
              21.9082027549759
            ],
            [
              39.1059115003141,
              21.9067334378047
            ],
            [
              39.1058490394627,
              21.9065906701445
            ],
            [
              39.1057955015902,
              21.9064508768104
            ],
            [
              39.1057776556326,
              21.9063110834761
            ],
            [
              39.1057776556326,
              21.9061504698582
            ],
            [
              39.1059352949243,
              21.9054098626202
            ],
            [
              39.1059858584705,
              21.9052700692861
            ],
            [
              39.1060929342158,
              21.9050975583632
            ],
            [
              39.1062416505286,
              21.9049369447453
            ],
            [
              39.1063544369804,
              21.9048531877179
            ],
            [
              39.1070597092225,
              21.9044120356475
            ],
            [
              39.1072253197085,
              21.9043135259617
            ],
            [
              39.1075679620934,
              21.9041403012006
            ],
            [
              39.1074993939589,
              21.9039598190834
            ],
            [
              39.1074565636607,
              21.9037980157348
            ],
            [
              39.1073899387526,
              21.9036552480746
            ],
            [
              39.1072471710921,
              21.9033126056897
            ],
            [
              39.1127949240849,
              21.9025555008554
            ],
            [
              39.1132113297609,
              21.9030849309291
            ],
            [
              39.1134909164293,
              21.9034477987326
            ],
            [
              39.1138418869276,
              21.90392666526
            ],
            [
              39.1139430140203,
              21.9040902532041
            ],
            [
              39.1156304484503,
              21.9067487060129
            ],
            [
              39.1137855730171,
              21.9078258086948
            ],
            [
              39.1137290608183,
              21.9078525776312
            ],
            [
              39.1135595242216,
              21.9079537047239
            ],
            [
              39.1134881403914,
              21.9080131912491
            ],
            [
              39.1133602443623,
              21.9081321642993
            ],
            [
              39.1132298816253,
              21.9082940033398
            ],
            [
              39.1131747376165,
              21.9083760233606
            ],
            [
              39.1130605234882,
              21.9086008824257
            ],
            [
              39.1130141239987,
              21.9087900495757
            ],
            [
              39.1129927088495,
              21.9090120532875
            ],
            [
              39.1129965159872,
              21.9090977138836
            ],
            [
              39.1130174552439,
              21.9092880707641
            ],
            [
              39.1130498159137,
              21.9095755096537
            ],
            [
              39.1130783694458,
              21.9098362985798
            ],
            [
              39.1131773550236,
              21.9105501368817
            ],
            [
              39.1132059085558,
              21.9106890974044
            ],
            [
              39.1132573049135,
              21.9108318650647
            ],
            [
              39.113329640528,
              21.9109765362938
            ],
            [
              39.1134210118307,
              21.9111040754037
            ],
            [
              39.1135295152526,
              21.9112335180826
            ],
            [
              39.113601850867,
              21.9112982394217
            ],
            [
              39.1137255828395,
              21.9114010321372
            ],
            [
              39.1138340862614,
              21.9114714641831
            ],
            [
              39.1139197468575,
              21.9115152462655
            ],
            [
              39.1141253322883,
              21.9115970997241
            ],
            [
              39.1150433174384,
              21.911944570432
            ],
            [
              39.1186921019178,
              21.9131436998059
            ],
            [
              39.1206730032052,
              21.9137861542774
            ],
            [
              39.1206730032052,
              21.9142977383938
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "PHID": 167781,
      "LMID": 167690,
      "FILE_ID": 167782,
      "CREATED_DATE": "2015-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "CREATED_BY": "Admin01",
      "FILE_FEATURE_ID": 1
    },
    "id": "LAYERS_GEOMETRY_DATA.167783"
  }]
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Type can be different like multiline string or polygon